# bubble-message with avatar images and avatar name with time-stamps

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, chat, uibubbletableview

I have to implement bubble messages with the `senders AVATAR` and `Sender's name with  time-stamps` same as below screen shot.

I have successfully implemented the `simple bubble type messaging`. Right now I have some good Git-hub projects which provide me but what I need is something different.

I had even used [acanichat](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/acanichat) but no luck.

so can anyone suggest me good tutorial for the same? or anyone have already done this with this [Git-hub Library](https://github.com/AlexBarinov/UIBubbleTableView) or with any other library?

I want a bubble-message with the `senders AVATAR` and `Sender's name with  time-stamps`, please take a look at following image.

[image]

Your suggestion are appreciable.

Comment: When people cant answer the question..they just think that its off topic... i bet you... too many people searching this kind of things with avtar and all kind of facility on the bubble chat... its very rude behaviour...

Answer (score 1):

Why not you create your own chat Table ? You just need to create Two custom Cells and With the help of XIB file you can give any Look you want.

Use Differentiators and conditions like Below.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{

 static NSString *CellIdentifier1 = @"Cell1";
 static NSString *CellIdentifier2 = @"Cell2";

CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(messageWidth-20, 10000000);
CGSize itemTextSize = [messageText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                              constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                                  lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
float textHeight = itemTextSize.height+7;


 if (messageType isEqualToString:@"textByme"]) { 

 CustomCell1  *cell = (CustomCell1 *)[self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier1];

        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell1" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }



 UIImageView *bubbleImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"chatbubble"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:15]];
        bubbleImage.tag=55;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:bubbleImage];
        [bubbleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(255-itemTextSize.width,5,itemTextSize.width+10,textHeight)];
  UITextView *messageTextview=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(250-itemTextSize.width,0,itemTextSize.width+15, textHeight)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:messageTextview];
        messageTextview.editable=NO;
        messageTextview.text = messageText;
        messageTextview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
        messageTextview.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;
        messageTextview.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13.0];
        messageTextview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        messageTextview.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.Avatar_Image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar.png"];
        cell.time_Label.text=data.messageTime;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        messageTextview.scrollEnabled=NO;

  return cell; 


}
else{

CustomCell2  *cell = (CustomCell2 *)[self.tableview dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier2];

        if (cell == nil) {
            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell2" owner:self options:nil];
            cell = [topLevelObjects objectAtIndex:0];
        }



   UIImageView *bubbleImage=[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[[UIImage   imageNamed:@"chatbubble"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:15 topCapHeight:15]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:bubbleImage];
        [bubbleImage setFrame:CGRectMake(50,5, itemTextSize.width+10, textHeight)];
        bubbleImage.tag=56;

        UITextView *messageTextview=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50,0,itemTextSize.width+15, textHeight)];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:messageTextview];
        messageTextview.editable=NO;
        messageTextview.text = messageText;
        messageTextview.dataDetectorTypes=UIDataDetectorTypeAll;
        messageTextview.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentJustified;
        messageTextview.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        messageTextview.font=[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue" size:13.0];
        messageTextview.scrollEnabled=NO;
        messageTextview.tag=indexPath.row;
        cell.Avatar_Image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar"];
        cell.time_Label.text=feed_data.messageTime;
        cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;

  return cell; 

}

}
```

For Height:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
float cellHeight;
        // text
        NSString *messageText = @"Your text";
        //
        CGSize boundingSize = CGSizeMake(messageWidth-20, 10000000);
        CGSize itemTextSize = [messageText sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]
                                      constrainedToSize:boundingSize
                                          lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];

        // plain text
        cellHeight = itemTextSize.height;

        if (cellHeight<25) {

            cellHeight=25;
        }
        return cellHeight+30;
}
```

Comment: yes i have somewhat implemented it..but my only problem is with dynamic size of bubble image

Comment: That you can Calculate By the height , check my edited Answer.